# jsf: iterate in jsp

Tags: java, jsf

I am using jsf framework and want to iterate a list of Integers in jsp. The result should look something like the following: 1  2  3  4.

The tags datascroller and datalist does not work in my case and it seems like jsf isnt very compatible with jstl tags. It stumbled upon x:iterator and x:forEach tag but didnt get it to work (actually the tags werent even recognized, so I must have missed some library, to begin with, but couldnt find out which library).

Thanx for all help.

/Cissi

Answer (score 1):

The Core tags eg `<c:forEach>` should work as long as you aren't mixing them with JSF iterators - for example don't use them inside something like `<h:dataTable>`. This is because the JSTL/Core tags are evaluated before any JSF iterator.

Otherwise try something like Richfaces `<a4j:repeat>` or move away from JSPs and into Facelets (if you can, then definitely do this) and use `<ui:repeat>`